# Foot rig , Looking for a way to lift foot by just rotating foot controller

Tags: rigging

Regarding the title, I am trying to create a rig that allow me to lift my foot heel up by just rotating the foot controller 's X axis. [image]

Currently, I'm able to lift my foot up whenever I rotate the foot controller toward positive rotation.

Now I, would like to have the root to rotate toward another direction whenever the foot controller is rotate toward negative X

[image]

something like the image shown above.

Link to my blender file

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for what animators call *foot roll*.  Here is a generic example of how to implement this so that one foot control controls both the forward and backward rotation of the bone:

[image: Generic foot control bones]

[image: Table of how each bone is used]

1. This rig relies on a combination of rotation constraints and parenting to cause the bones to roll in the desired fashion.  Because of that none of the bones are connected, but certain bones have to be properly positioned relating to each other:

- The Toe and Reverse bones are in opposite directions with the head of the Toe in the same position as the head of the Reverse.
- The Head of the Forward bone is in the same position as the tail of the Reverse bone.
- All of the bones lie in the same plane along the Y axis.
- The bone roll and axis orientation are relevant
- The Forward and Control bone are parallel to the Z axis

2. It is common to use the foot bone as the controller for the leg IK chain.  In that case the Forward and Control bones can be parented to the root bone.